# C++ Can't read UTF-8 cyrillic text from file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, utf-8, cyrillic, cfile

The file is UTF-8 (65001) encoded. I can't read cyrillic symbols from it.

```
CString FNAME;
CStdiofile fNFR;

fNFR.Open(_T("LFS200.25"), CFile::modeRead);
fNFR.ReadString(FNAME);
```

And got this:

```
 Р—РёРјРЅРёР№ РјР°РєСЃРёРјСѓРј 1989/90 РіРі.
```

instead of this:

```
 Зимний максимум 1989/90 гг.
```

Tried

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
```

Still the same problem.

How to get proper string?

Comment: This *is* UTF8. C++ has 16-bit characters (char16_t) and strings but UTF8 strings are treated as char. If you want to convert the UTF8 bytes to UTF16 you need codecvt

Comment: Check [this question on UTF support in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11) and the [String and Character Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) page in MSDN

Comment: Check [codecvt_utf8_utf16](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16). You should be able to convert your UTF8 string to UTF16 with `std::u16string u16_conv = std::wstring_convert<  std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>{}.from_bytes(u8);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here (need to convert utf-8 to utf-16):

[CONVERSION BETWEEN UNICODE UTF-16 AND UTF-8 IN C++/WIN32](http://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2010/01/04/conversion-between-unicode-utf-16-and-utf-8-in-c-win32/)

Comment: That's *not* a good solution. It was written 7 years ago, when C++ didn't have native Unicode support. In the end, it's just a call to `WideCharToMultiByte`. I'm 100% certain that the author would tell you today "Don't do this!".

Comment: Or [initialize CStdioFile with a UTF8 FILE stream](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17378096/134204)